# Why always Web component(Custom component)'s shadow-root copy own root's style

Tags: html, css, web-component, custom-component

I create and use a web component.

and I give a some style to web component.
After then always web component inject own style to shadow-root.

This is code.

```
<custom-element style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid red" />
```

And I can see this dom structure in devTool's element tab

```
<custom-element style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid red">
   #shadow-root
   <div style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid red">
      ~~~~
   </div>
</custom-element>
```

But, I want to give a style to only custom-element.
Or give a style to only shadow-root, How can I do this?

....................................................

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.